# Copying a variable's value to another?

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I have two variables, I need to move the values from string1 to string2.

```
string1 DB 20, 22 dup('?')
string2 DB 20, 22 dup('?')
```

I know how to do this with a register (si) and a loop, something like:

```
LEA si, string1
LEA di, string2
mov cx, 5
change:
mov ax, [si]
mov [di], ax
loop change
```

I want to know if there is a shorter method.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are `REP` (Repeat) and `MOVSB` (A mnemonic for **MOV**e **S**tring **B**yte).

Example:

```
lea     si,[string1] ;si points to string1
lea     di,[string2] ;di points to string2
mov     cx,5         ;number of bytes in string1
rep     movsb        ;copy the string
```

See also:

```
MOVSW (Move String Word - Copies 2 bytes at a time)
MOVSD (Move String DWord - Copies 4 bytees at a time)
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to clear the direction flag with `CLD` prior to using `REP`, otherwise you can end up with interesting bugs.